# Django login after registration

Tags: python, django

Im' trying to auto login the user after registration but anything seems to work.

Does not work:

```
if registroForm.is_valid():
        registroForm.save()
        user = authenticate(username=registroForm.cleaned_data['username'], password=registroForm.cleaned_data['password1'])
        request.session['_auth_user_id'] = user.pk
        request.session['_auth_user_backend'] = user.backend
        return JsonResponse({})
```

Does not work:

```
if registroForm.is_valid():
        registroForm.save()
        usuario = authenticate(username=registroForm.cleaned_data['username'], password=registroForm.cleaned_data['password1'])
        login(request, usuario)
        return JsonResponse({})
```

I'm using Django 2.0

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it per the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/):

```
def post(self,request):
    form = self.form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, username, password)
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(request.POST['next']))
    context = {'form' : form,
               'title': self.title,
               'myurl' : self.myurl,
               'submit': self.submit,
               'nexturl' : self.nexturl,
               }
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

For my application, I had to add some additional stuff into the context in case of a failed validation.  You should be able to just pass the form there.

**Edit:**

You do not want to use `authenticate` here.  Since this is registration, you need to create the new user (`create_user()`) then call `login` with the information for that user (this is the lines in the middle of that code block right after`except`).  Then redirect to a profile update page where you can prompt the user for the additional information you want to store with the user.

Comment: `create_user` receives username, email and password... and I need extra fields. Anyway, I get the user with the `authenticate` method, I do the login, all ok, but the user do not log in.

Comment: @Jota I updated my answer to include more information

Comment: It works for me.  Either you did not copy it correctly or you are doing something else that is giving you problems

Comment: @Jota Edit what you have now into the question.  That works much better than trying to debug blindly.

Comment: The user is created, does the login and the page redirects to he main page (like your code) but the new user never got log in unless he logs in manually.

Comment: @jota If the login worked, they will still be logged in until there is a logout.  Like I said, edit what you have now into the question.